# How to add php script to forward a copy of a form

Tags: joomla

Currently using Joomlashine JSN Uniforms on a beta site. I need to send a duplicate submission to another email address. However, JSN Uniforms canot do this ATM, but there is Script section in form admin panel which includes

Custom Scripts (PHP) called on form processing
The $html string contains the HTML code of the form. You can modify it by adding a PHP script below. Remember to not include the  tags.

On form Process
The $post variable contains $_POST data of the form. You can modify it by adding a PHP script below, before it is added to the database. Remember to not include the  tags.

After form has been processed
The $post variable contains $_POST data of the form. You can modify it by adding a PHP script below, after form been processed successfully. Remember to not include the  tags.

Form Setup

Name
email
subject
department (pulldown) 1. Sales & Service 2. Training & Standards
Message
send

Department: Sales & Service has 2 email addresses (at the moment Uniforms can only assign 1 email address

user1@company.com
user2@companny.com

is there a script I can use to have the submitted form send to the Department user2@company.com and have the form sent to user1@company.com

Comment: obviously I am using Joomla 3

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved by not messing around with Joomla but adjusting the email service to forward/alias to one address and simply setup Outlook client for  each use for the primary email address